# Error if comment in json when using Ext.decode() in ExtJS 7

Tags: extjs, extjs7

Ext.decode() is very strict now. It throws error when there's a comment in the JSON or any invalid json format, such as no double quote.
How can I disable such checking?

```
Ext.decode('{ test: test}');
OR
Ext.decode(`{//test 
    "include": [
        "main.json"
    ]
}`)
```

Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:

But this will not throw error in 6.2.0

Comment: What JSON file are you talking about? Comments are actually invalid in JSON but some tools still ignore them.

Comment: well, some json config for my project. I get error when running sencha app build.

Comment: Could you please clarify which one and what error you get?

Comment: I'm so sorry, it's not the error during build. It's run time error when it tries to Ext.decode(text). I have update the question. sorry about that.

Comment: Decode method has a 2nd param, if set to true, method wont throw an error and will return null instead. Nevertheless, like Jonas said, comments in json are not allowed.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.html#method-decode

Comment: thanks for reply. but i saw the same thing on 6.2.0 documentation. but it didnt throw error. Weird. https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.html#method-decode

tested on sencha fiddle, it only throws error starting 6.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Like devbnz mentioned, there's a 2nd param, if set to true, method wont throw an error and will return null instead.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.html#method-decode

But yet prior to 6.6.0, Ext.decode() still can accept invalid json. It was fixed in 6.6.0
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/guides/whats_new/release_notes.html

EXTJS-18443 JSON decoder should throw exception on invalid syntax

[UPDATE] My answer is wrong. There's no solution for now. You cannot decode a JSON with comment using Ext.decode in ExtJs7